# angular material autocomplete filter not working

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I have setup a material autocomplete field with filtering on one page of my app and it works perfectly fine.

I want to setup another one on another page, using the same code, but on this new one, everything works except the filter.

On the first one which is working, if I track value changes by logging to console, I got a log each time the value changes, either by selecting or typing text in field.

In the second one, I made the same test, and nothing goes to the console.

So it's sound value change is never triggered, but I don't understand why.

Here are excerpts of my code.

HTML template

```
                    <mat-form-field *ngIf="!this.globalVariables.adminUser.ownSiteUserAdmin" appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label i18n>Site</mat-label>
                        <input fxFlex matInput formControlName="siteSelector" [matAutocomplete]="autoSiteForm"
                            i18n-placeholder placeholder="Type text to filter Sites">
                        <mat-autocomplete #autoSiteForm="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="this.utils.displayItemLabel">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let suggestedSite of filteredSuggestedSites | async "
                                [value]="suggestedSite">
                                {{suggestedSite.label}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-autocomplete>
                        <mat-hint i18>Click to select Site</mat-hint>
                        <mat-error>
                            <div *ngIf="selectedSite.hasError('required')" i18n>Site is required.</div>
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

I have tried by replacing formControlName by [formControl] but same issue.

Form declaration

```
    this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        title: [''],
        firstName: ['', Validators.required],
        lastName: ['', Validators.required],
        telephone: ['', Validators.pattern(GlobalConstantsService.PHONE_REGEX_PATTERN)],
        email: ['', { updateOn: 'change', validators: Validators.pattern(GlobalConstantsService.EMAIL_REGEX_PATTERN) }],
        description: [''],
        userName: ['', Validators.required, this.isUserNameValidValidator.validate.bind(this.isUserNameValidValidator)],
        password: ['', Validators.required],
        accountStartDate: [''],
        accountEndDate: [''],
        siteSelector: [null, Validators.required]
      },
      {
        updateOn: 'submit'
      },
    );
```

Subscription to change in ngOnInit

```
    this.filteredSuggestedSites = this.userFormGroup.get('siteSelector').valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this.utils._filterItemSelector(value, this.suggestedSites))
      );
```

Filter function

```
  _filterItemSelector(value: string, items: ItemSelector[]): ItemSelector[] {
     if (typeof value === 'string') {
      const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
      return items.filter(item => item.label.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
    } else {
      // value is an ItemSelector i.e. user has selected a value i.e. filter is not needed
      return items;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

So stupid I am, first one is update on change, second one is update on submit.

I add update on change on field with autocomplete only, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```html
(input)="onInputChange($event.target.value)"
```

add the above line to the `mat-form-field`

onInputChange(value: string) {

```
this.filteredParams = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(value),
  tap(value => console.log("Value: ", value)),
  map(val => this._filter(val)),
);
```

}

this will work fine